# Is BufferedReader blocking the standard console input?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I'm writing a simple chat application in Java and everything works fine except the following strange bug:

When you type something in the terminal, for example you press "a" and the console writes "a", then you press "i", it writes "i", "r" -> "r"... and you get the word (e.g. "air") written in console.

In my case I press "e", the console writes "(nothing)", "i" ->"(noting)", "r" -> (nothing) and only after I pressed "enter" console suddenly displays the whole word "air", works in the same way with more than one words. In reality the user can write whatever he/she wants but the typed down text will appear only after Enter has been pressed.

In my program I use a `BufferedReader` object to read from the socket:

```
try( ....some socket stuff....
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);//out is the socket output
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); //in is the socket input

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //that's the standard input, the one from keyboard
 while(true){
          if (stdIn.ready()){
            userInput=stdIn.readLine();
            out.println(userInput);
            if(userInput.equals("Bye.")) break;
            System.out.println("Me: "+userInput);
          }

          if(in.ready()){
          if((serverInput= in.readLine())!=null){
              System.out.println("Stranger: "+serverInput);
            }

          }
```

In my opinion that methods - `ready` and `readline()` - probably bug the console. It seems a little bit weird for me but it's Java and I'm not very skilled.

Apart from that the chat works like charm - it sends and receives properly. The read-receive-input script is exactly the same and on the client side. When you're typing a message nothing will show up in console but it actually is there and on Enter it displays, it's not a delay, it's influenced by Enter.

Comment: How are you calling the application? I tried a similar piece of code and it works for me, my guess your environment is suppressing the input from the terminal, and the reason it is printed on enter is because of the `out.println(userInput);` line

Comment: #ecarlos
I initialize the program with java ServerSide <portnumber> and java ClientSide <ip> <portnumber> then it just works... the Server has its Serversocket and a normal socket with uses .accept() method. Nothing special at all it u just can't see what you are typing while you are typing it, that's the annoying part. Can you suggest what may "suppress" the input from the terminal?

Comment: You've somehow got the console into no echo mode. It doesn't have anything to do with `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible to do in java. 
At least not with platform independent way.

What you are trying to do is, read character by character, without pressing enter key.
But the console on os itself by default is in buffered line mode.

So, only solution is to put your console on raw mode (line editing bypassed and no enter key required), making it platform dependent.

Edit : Your description says character reading, and your code is doing something else by the way.

Comment: Yeah , it is not my will the console not to display what the user is typing while he/she is typing, it happens by itself and I can't find out why my code causes it. Can you suggest me a method or something to read? Whatever I write in console, commands, other text this issue does not appear, it's only in this particular case. Maybe I'm not understanding something well, sorry if it is so.